# How to texture a complex mesh/multiple meshes?

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects

I am a beginner in Blender. I have created a handgun after a reference, and I believe I have made a few mistakes. When it came to dents, I used "loop cut" to manually show them, but I do not believe I will be able to do this in the future (too many polygons and loop cuts for every single dent or additive). I also did this for holes.

There are several objects/meshes that are separate. I am completely lost when it comes to texturing the gun after the reference image. Should I join all of the meshes/objects into one object and then texture? If so, how would I go about texturing every single aspect that I need present. I apologise if this seems complicated or confusing, I am a true beginner. (I have watched a few tutorials)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE! We're glad to have you here! Your question might get closed as "off topic" because it's so broad, but don't worry, that doesn't mean it's a bad question. This just isn't quite the right site for this kind of broad "how do I texture things?" question. That being said, I'll write up a little answer that will at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this problem. To begin with, you can choose to use materials for everything (totally viable), to use textures for everything (also totally viable), but I think the best option is to use a mixture of both.

Often, the best approach is to use materials for anything that can all be the same, and use textures for anything that needs to be placed carefully (like a label or logo).

In your case, I'd recommend that you `join` all the parts that will be the same material into the same object (like all the individual components that make up the slide, for example). All of those meshes don't have to necessarily be connected to each other, they'll just be in the same object. Then you can give the object one material that looks like anodized steel (or whatever). I suspect you'll have an object for the slide, another for the grip and lower receiver, another for the magazine butt, another for the magazine itself, another for the extractor, another for each of the controls (safe selector, magazine release, slide lock/release), and a few others. Note that meshes can be in the same object even if they're not close to each other. For example, the magazine release and the safety might be in the same object, if they're supposed to be the same material. That way you can set up the material for both at the same time.

Once you've done that, determine if there are any parts that should be textures. If you're going to be adding the manufacturer's mark, that's probably a good candidate. You also might find it easier to make the nerling on the grip as a normal map than try to model it.

Those are some basic ideas that will get you a little closer, but beyond that we're getting into making a tutorial, which is outside the scope of this website ;-) I wish you the best of luck, and do remember to check back here when you have specific, answerable questions. Happy Blending!