# How do I UV Unwrap extremely complicated meshes? i.e: A blanket or a octagonal table?

Tags: texturing, uv

I've gotten a couple of meshes from the internet and I need to texture them for a class project. I've learnt the basics of unwrapping cones, spheres, cubes etc. but when it comes to more complex objects, I'm clueless.

So how would I UV unwrap something like a blanket draped over a bed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same exact question was asked literally five posts down https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87421/how-to-texture-a-complex-mesh-multiple-meshes

Comment: When it comes to unwrapping, every case is different: some need seams, some don't. Some you can project from view, some need more intricate ways. In the case of an octagonal table you might want to select the top view and do project from view for the top and bottom parts of the table and mark a seam and follow active quads for the sides. For a blanket (if it is already distorted) follow active quads might be useful, it's hard to tell without seeing the model. In short there is no universal approach that works in all circumstances.

Comment: I recommend that you read (yes... read, not watch tutorial) through the manual, the section for UV Unwapping is quite detailed. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/index.html?highlight=unwrap

Comment: Suggestion.  Show your work in a screen capture of  Blender UV Image Editor.  Some people might find your question crystal clear.  If I only read what you wrote  ... I find your question vague.  A question such as .... How do I improve my current UV Unwrap, shown here, to achieve purpose X? ... might be clearer.  Please show more consideration for the readers of your question, with more thought.